# make: riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc: Command not found.But i have set .bashrc in /etc/profile

Tags: path, riscv

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFjt7.png)

```
cgf@lzp:~/xv6-k210$ ls
bootloader  debug  doc  fs.img  img  kernel  LICENSE  linker  Makefile  README  README_cn.md  README.md  target  tools  xv6-user
cgf@lzp:~/xv6-k210$ sudo make fs
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -Wall -Werror -O -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ggdb -g -MD -mcmodel=medany -ffreestanding -fno-common -nostdlib -mno-relax -I.    -c -o xv6-user/ulib.o xv6-user/ulib.c
make: riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'xv6-user/ulib.o' failed
make: *** [xv6-user/ulib.o] Error 127
cgf@lzp:~/xv6-k210$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
cgf@lzp:~/xv6-k210$ which riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc
/usr/local/riscvtc/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc
```

make does`t find the command

what ${PATH} is make using??

which riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc can find the location of this executable file.

Comment: i think error is not that comman is not found ,    it is no input files   , So it may be  your make command is passing wrong arumnets to command , please check make what command it is performing .

Answer (score 0):

When running your make command with sudo. The PATH is not the same. You are using the secure PATH. You have two possibilities:

1. update the secure PATH by executing `sudo visudo`.
2. Run `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" make fs`.